# OBIEE 12.2.1.2 Can not delete catalog folder? Error: Shortcut expected

Tags: oracle, directory, delete-file, obiee, catalog

I want to delete an old_folder from my shared catalog folders, however, the following error message is displayed: Shortcut expected /shared/old_folder/...

The same message appears in the catalog manager. Deleting single objects (analyses, prompts, ...) works fine: folders and subfolders within the given folder can not be deleted.

Concerning the permissions: I have full control of the folder/objects.

Ideas and suggestions are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Explanation: He means the .atr (Attribute files) which accompany any presentation catalog folder or file on the file system - i.e. phyiscally on the disk.

NOTE: This isn't something you do lightly.

a) Never touch just a file / folder without taking care of its accompanying .atr file

b) And vice versa. You can't just delete .atr files without also deleting their parent object - be it folder or file.

tl;dr - this should NOT be the very first you one does...

Comment: This was my guess, too. Before doing anything rash I wanted to be sure. Thanks for the help!